# Java Swing. using a single button to read from txt files and print to a text area

Tags: java, swing, filereader

Sorry I'm quite the beginner. I'm building a password generator that reads a list of nouns from txt file and picks a random one and prints it to text field.

The same process will be used for a list of adjectives. The end result I planned will be

- random noun +
- random adjective +
- random string of characters (!?$ etc.)

All of this is being done from a single button.

I got the noun part to work in the action listener. But for organization purposes I moved the actions into their own separate methods and then called the methods into the action listener. I can't get the noun part to work anymore after moving it into its own method.

code: The top part is the one that works and is commented out. The bottom part is where I tried to separate it into its own method and I can't get to work.

```
Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method nouns(String) in the type PassWord is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

```
Generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
                nouns();
                
                
                /*
                File file = new File("nouns.txt"); 
  
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = sc.nextLine();
                         if(line.length() > 0) {
                             lines.add(line);
                             //System.out.print(line);
                             Collections.shuffle(lines);
                             String pickNoun = lines.get(0);
                             
                             output.setText(pickNoun);
                
                         }
    
                    
                    }} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                */
                
                
                
               
            }
        });
        
        
    }
    
        public static void nouns(String noun) {
            File file = new File("nouns.txt"); 
            
            try {
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                     if(line.length() > 0) {
                         lines.add(line);
                         //System.out.print(line);
                         Collections.shuffle(lines);
                         String pickNoun = lines.get(0);
                         String noun = pickNoun;
                         pickNoun = noun;
                         //noun.setText(pickNoun);
                         //output.setText(pickNoun);
            
                     }

                
                }} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: noun() expects a parameter String. Remove the parameter and it should work. Didn't watch the rest of your code.

Comment: First and foremost, *never* try to run code that doesn't first compile

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you exactly what the error is:

```
The method nouns(String) in the type PassWord is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Your method firm is:

```
public static void nouns(String noun) {
```

So it's expecting you to pass a `String noun` to it (probably you're trying to return one, so it should be changed to:

And you're calling it as:

```
nouns();
```

No parameter inside, so either, remove the String parameter from the method firm or pass a String to the method, I'd remove the String parameter as you're not using it anywhere inside the method.

I see a couple of errors here:

1. You want to return a `String noun` from your method `nouns`

   ```
    public String getRandomNoun() {
        //Your logic here
        return randomNoun; //randomNoun is a String
    }
   ```
2. As you can see above I removed the `static` keyword as you should have that inside a class instance (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem was I my naming of the methods and the structure of my code. My action listener was inside the main method. I had to include static to pass them to the to listener I think. Don't know if my solution was optimal I'm beginner but this is it.

```
Generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
            output.setText(nouns() + adjective() + Random() + randomChar());

        }
    });
    
    
}

    public static String nouns() {
        File file = new File("nouns.txt"); 
        String noun = null;
        try {
            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                 if(line.length() > 0) {
                     lines.add(line);
                     Collections.shuffle(lines);
                     String pickNoun = lines.get(0);
                     noun = pickNoun;
                
        
                 }

            
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return noun;

}
    
    
    
    
    public static String adjective() {
        File file = new File("adjectives.txt"); 
        String Adj = null;
        try {
            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                 if(line.length() > 0) {
                     lines.add(line);
                     Collections.shuffle(lines);
                     String pickAdj = lines.get(0);
                     Adj = pickAdj;
        
                 }

            
            }

             
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Adj;

}
    
    public static int Random() {
        
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom(); 
          
        // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999 
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000); 
        
        return rand_int1;
    }
    
    public static String randomChar() {
    
        int leftLimit = 33; // !
        int rightLimit = 45; // -
        int targetStringLength = 3;
        Random random = new Random();
     
        String ran = random.ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1)
              .limit(targetStringLength)
              .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
              .toString();

        return ran;

    }
```

}